# NBitcoin throws InvalidOperationException with the message: "Mac HMACSHA256 not recognised."

Tags: c#, .net, bitcoin

I got the message when I try to sign a transaction:

```
Transaction payment = new Transaction();
BitcoinSecret PaymentSecret = new BitcoinSecret("1sXCvdpXz...UqkXW9mvT");
...
payment.Sign(Container.PaymentSecret, false);
```

I dig into the opensource NBitcoin API and figured out these lines give me the error message. What can I do? (https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/Crypto/DeterministicECDSA.cs)

```
try
{
    hmac = MacUtilities.GetMac(macName);
}
catch(SecurityUtilityException nsae)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(nsae.Message, nsae);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was here:

> NBitcoin/NBitcoin.BouncyCastle/security/MacUtilities.cs

```
public static IMac GetMac(string algorithm)
{
    ...
    if(mechanism.StartsWith("HMAC"))
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The mechanism string is "HMACSHA256" and the if statement never evaluates true for me, because my language is Hungarian and "CS" is a letter in Hungarian. So according to the StartsWith function "HMACSHA256" doesn't start with "HMAC" in Hungarian.

The issue has been fixed in the NBitcoin API by Nicolas Dorier as adding StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase setting to the StartWith function.

In case someone wants to test it, here's an email from Nicolas:

> Ok, for history.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("hu"); 
string mechanism = "HMACSHA256"; 
var v1 = mechanism.StartsWith("HMAC");

mechanism = "HMAC-SHA256"; 
var v2 = mechanism.StartsWith("HMAC");
```

> In hungarian, v1 is false and v2 true.

Answer (score 1):

If someone would like to figure out what is happening exactly, here's a code snippet that'll cause the bug:

```
    string mechanism = "HMACSHA256";
    if (mechanism.StartsWith("HMAC"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("good");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bad");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

If you set mechanism = "HMAC-SHA256", then the bug won't happen.
If you use mechanism.StartsWith("HMAC",StringComparison.InvariantCulture), then bug won't happen.

I've also fixed the bug in github and created a pull request to the NBitcoin API, so hopefully it won't happen with others in the future.

Comment: I copy and pasted this code, and it works fine on my machine. What is your language please ? this is a very intriguing bug.

Comment: I was thinking, maybe stackoverflow does some magic here, but I've created a new project, copypasted, and the bug is still present.

Comment: I have Hungarian keyboard, but running every software in my computer (windows, visualstudio) in English. Also I'm in Taiwan right now, but that shouldn't matter. I have sent you in mail my `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`, hope that'll help.

Answer (score -1):

There is a hyphen after HMAC. HMAC-SHA256

Answer (score -1):

I just tried the code on my machine, and it works perfectly.

```
public void CanSignSimple()
{
    Key bob = new Key();
    Transaction tx = new Transaction();
    tx.Inputs.Add(new TxIn()
    {
        ScriptSig = bob.ScriptPubKey
    });
    tx.Sign(bob, false);
}
```

It should be noted that I am not using Bouncy castle library now. I copied the needed part of bouncycastle INSIDE NBitcoin.
Your bug seems like you are using NBitcoin along with the official BouncyCastle, which can happen only if you recompiled everything yourself with using the official BouncyCastle lib, OR you are using an old version of NBitcoin.

What version are you using ?

Comment: None of that is the case, I'm using the most recent one with NuGet.

I've just built myself the NBitcoin.dll.
In the `DeterministicECDSA.cs` file / `public DeterministicECDSA(String hashName)` function, if I change the `macName` variable manually to `"HMAC-SHA256"` instead of `"HMACSHA256"` it will work.
What is the value of the `macName` variable at you when you debug it before the `hmac = MacUtilities.GetMac(macName);` line?

Comment: Can you run the code I gave you ? I just created new project, installed nbitcoin and runned the code and don't manage to reproduce your bug. My version is without the "-", and by going step by step in MacUtilities, which is in NBitcoin source, it handle it correctly. (HMACSHA256)

Comment: From [MacUtilities](https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin.BouncyCastle/security/MacUtilities.cs#L103), you can see that I handle correctly both case, with and without dash.

Comment: Indeed. Everything seemed to be correct. I was playing around with the code and figured `if (mechanism.StartsWith("HMAC"))` just doesn't work as expected for some reason. Long story short, this solves my problem: `if (mechanism.StartsWith("HMAC", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))`. I have created a pull request for the original project on github.

Comment: I don't stop reviewing the code, and don't see the problem... look at how I fetch "mechanism", from an array where everything is upper case.

I will accept your PR, but I'd like to lean about why it did not work first.